# Override wp_link_pages pagebreak with filter

Tags: posts, wp-query, filters, pagination, wp-link-pages

Is it possible to have conditional pagebreaks?

For instance, if there is a match in the query string, the first page break of a post is ignored, and the user get's to read two posts in a row before clicking next?

Answer (score 0):

So I just found this filter:

`the_posts`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_posts

Send it to a function, and the first parameter is the entire post page with the pagebreak.

My plan is to run it through regex, delete the first occurence of the `<!--nextpage-->` and return it. I'll see if that works